# IF $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n|>c)=\infty\forall c>0$, then $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|S_n|=\infty$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

If $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i,i\ge 1$ are iid and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n|>c)=\infty\forall c>0$, then $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|S_n|=\infty$ a.s.

I tried this but got stuck:
Let $A_n=\{|X_n|>c\}$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)=\infty$ so by Borel-Cantelli, $P(|X_n|>c, i.o.)=1$

So $|X_n|>c$ a.s.

Then $\sum_{k=1}^n |X_k|>nc$ a.s.

But I do I relate $|S_n|=|\sum_{k=1}^nX_k|$ to this with the inequality in the direction I want? The triangle inequality doesn't help here.

Comment: "$P(|X_n|>c, i.o.)=1$... Then $\sum_{k=1}^n |X_k|>nc$ a.s." No.

Comment: so the a.s. part is only when $P(A_n, i.o.)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... almost surely, $|X_n|\gt c$ for infinitely many $n$. Note that if $|X_n|\gt c$, then $|S_n|\gt\frac12c$ or $|S_{n-1}|\gt\frac12c$. Hence  $|S_n|\gt\frac12c$ for infinitely many $n$, in particular, $\limsup\limits_n|S_n|\geqslant\frac12c$, almost surely. This holds for every $c$, say, every integer $c$, hence  $\limsup\limits_n|S_n|=+\infty$, almost surely.

Comment: why can it be $\limsup |S_n|\ge \frac{1}{2}$ almost surely? i don't understand where the almost surely came from.

Comment: $\frac12c$, not $\frac12$. Every property follows from the first one that $|X_n|\gt c$ for infinitely many $n$, and this one is only almost sure.

Comment: how can i show it's almost sure or not?

Comment: ?? You wrote it yourself: "$P(|X_n|>c, i.o.)=1$".

Comment: So $P(|X_n|>c,i.o.)=1$ is $|X_n|>c$ a.s.? But the comment on the question says no

Comment: No it is not. As written in the answer, this is [$|X_n|\gt c$ for infinitely many $n$, almost surely]. Say, do you know what "i.o." stands for?

Comment: i.o. is infinitely often